Access deep optional propety of an object with typescript bracket notation
I have a type generated by @graphql-codegen for a query result, and I need to use it as type variable for the ReactTable column utils createColumnHelper.
My query is paginated server-side, and the edges property I want to access in optional in the given query result type.
Typescript is giving me en error: Property 'edges' does not exist on type '{ total?: number | null | undefined; pageInfo: { hasNextPage: boolean; startCursor?: string | null | undefined; endCursor?: string | null | undefined; }; edges?: ({ cursor: string; node?: { ...; } | ... 1 more ... | undefined; } | null)[] | null | undefined; } | null | undefined'.(2339)
I don't understand why does it say it "does not exist" ?
Being sure it exists, how can I tell typescript that it exist ?
Here is a short reproduction of the problem :
type SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery = {
    supplierInvoiceListPaginated?: {
        total?: number | null,
        pageInfo: {
            hasNextPage: boolean,
            startCursor?: string | null,
            endCursor?: string | null
        },
        edges?: Array<{
            cursor: string,
            node?: {
                id: string,
                partnerId: string,
                referenceTo: string,
                amount: number,
                datespan?: Array<any> | null,
                docDate?: any | null,
            } | null
        } | null> | null
    } | null
};

let supplierInvoiceList: SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery["supplierInvoiceListPaginated"]["edges"]

=> ["edges"] is underlined with the above described error.
Playground Link
I tried to use the ! non-null assertion operator in different ways combined with bracket notation without success.

SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery["supplierInvoiceListPaginated"] could be undefined or null.
["edges"] doesn't exist on undefined or null.
You could exclude the nullish types and pluck the edges type from the result instead:
let supplierInvoiceList: Exclude<SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery["supplierInvoiceListPaginated"], undefined | null>["edges"]


Thank you @George ! It's exactly what I was looking for.
Simple, it get a bit convoluted when you have to apply that at several depths in the object, but it's straight forward and works fine.

@JulienLemaître It sure does. I often use a utility type like type NotNil<T> = Exclude<T, undefined | null> for that reason.

According to your problem definition, your goal is to define the type of supplierInvoiceList to the type of edges.
Here I would like to define some other types to simplify the type SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery. Here how I would like to re-define the above code:
type PageInfo = {
    hasNextPage: boolean,
    startCursor?: string | null,
    endCursor?: string | null
}

type EdgeNode = {
    id: string,
    partnerId: string,
    referenceTo: string,
    amount: number,
    datespan?: any[] | null,
    docDate?: any | null,
}

type Edge = {
    cursor: string,
    node?:  EdgeNode | null
}

type SupplierInvoiceListPaginatedQuery = {
    supplierInvoiceListPaginated?: {
        total?: number | null,
        pageInfo: PageInfo,
        edges?: Edge[] | null
    } | null
};

let supplierInvoiceList: Edge[] | null | undefined;

The code above is same to your desire but this way of code will help you to reuse your code and make it simple.

Thank you Kazi for your answer. In my use case, I cannot compose the initial type the way you propose because it is auto-generated by a library based on an existing graphql query. That is why I needed a way to extract the desired type from this given type.
